# shell script runs out of memory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, out-of-memory

I have written the following random-number generator shell script:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $1) #for as many times, as the first argument ($1) defines...
do 
echo "$i $((RANDOM%$2))" #print the current iteration number and a random number in [0, $2)
done
```

I run it like that:

```
./generator.sh 1000000000 101 > data.txt
```

to generate 1B rows of an id and a random number in [0,100] and store this data in file `data.txt`.

My desired output is:

```
1 39
2 95
3 61
4 27
5 85
6 44
7 49
8 75
9 52
10 66
...
```

It works fine for small number of rows, but with 1B, I get the following OOM error:

> ./generator.sh: xrealloc: ../bash/subst.c:5179: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes (4299137024 bytes allocated)

Which part of my program creates the error? 
How could I write the `data.txt` file line-by-line?
I have tried replacing the `echo` line with:

```
echo "$i $((RANDOM%$2))" >> $3
```

where $3 is `data.txt`, but I see no difference.

Comment: `seq 1000000000` means 10e9, which is a lot. I did a `seq 1000000000 > file` and before I stopped it, it was already 5G.

Comment: @fedorqui I know, but that's what I need. I want big data for my experiment, to prove the scalability of my algorithm. I don't have a problem with the file size, just wonder what I could do to avoid OOM error.

Comment: @fedorqui I got your point after reading Hari Shankar's answer. Thank you, too!

Comment: In fact I wasn't aware of what Hari commented, so all the honours go to him :)

Comment: @fedorqui, This issues is obviously due to problem already mentioned in comments & answers. My question is, however, Why did it not hit [MAX_ARG_STRLEN limit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) first? Or is it indeed hitting that limit? but if that is the case, the fault should not be a OOM in `bash`... Right?

Comment: @anishsane I don't know and I am also curious about it. Maybe you can create a question out of it, I am sure some Bash/Linux/c gurus can answer it!

Comment: Is it possibly because bash first calculates `$(...)` & keep it in memory. After the evaluation is complete, then it forms the command line for actual command `for...` part. But before the first step is completed, it receives OOM error.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178359 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(seq 1 $1)` is computing the whole list before iterating over it. So it takes memory to store the entire list of `10^9` numbers, which is a lot.

I am not sure if you can make `seq` run lazily, i.e, get the next number only when needed. You can do a simple for loop instead:

```
for ((i=0; i<$1;++i))
do
  echo "$i $((RANDOM%$2))"
done
```

Comment: "*not sure if you can make seq run lazily*": This is a shell script, of course you can! You can just pipe the output to `while`, which will read it line-by-line (see my answer).

Answer (score 10):

The problem is your `for` loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $1)
```

This will *first* expand `$(seq 1 $1)`, creating a very big list, which you then pass to `for`.

Using `while`, however, we can read the output of `seq` line-by-line, which will take a small amount of memory:

```
seq 1 1000000000 | while read i; do
        echo $i
done
```

Comment: nice! In fact you can avoid the pipe by saying `while read -r i; do ... done < <(seq ...)`

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks; that's faster, but also uglier, IMHO :-) I would opt for readability unless there's a good (performance) reason not to (usually one pipe doesn't matter that much performance-wise, although there are exceptions!).

Comment: Well, there is a pitfall with `something | while`: if you want to change variables in the `while` loop, they won't be. This is because the variable from the original shell is copied in the new shell, but the changes do not affect the original one. See this good reading: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: Thanks @Carpetsmoker. Can you please clarify for me why this answer is better than Hari's? Is it faster? Hari's answer works as well (even if it takes a long time).

Comment: Actually, after 1 hour, it is still running, having written 161M lines so far... But I guess the bottleneck is RANDOM, not the for loop

Comment: @vefthym It's not "better"; it's just a different solution for the same problem. I thought it would add some value to your understanding on why this fails, and scripting in general. Hari's answer works only for numbers, and is probably best for this specific problem, but I haven't tested it. It's also bash-specific non-portable syntax, if you care about that ... This solution also works with other input, such as a line of text; it's also portable (fedorqui's suggestion isn't btw).

Comment: @vefthym Well, that's easy to test; remove the RANDOM, do a test run outputting to `/dev/null` ...

Comment: @vefthym The bottleneck is calling echo for every single number

Comment: Why isn't my suggestion portable?

Answer (score 4):

If you want it fast this should work.

You will need to compile it using g++ using the form

```
g++ -o <executable> <C++file>
```

For example i did it this way

```
g++ -o inseq.exe CTest.cpp
```

CTest.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
        for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
        {
                ss << i << "\n";
                if(i%10000==0)
                {
                        std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
                        ss.clear();
                        ss.str(std::string());

                }
        }
std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
ss.clear();
ss.str(std::string());
}
```

### Speed comparisons

Lowest speeds of 3 tests for each of the methods presented for a 1000000 line file.

#### Jidder

```
$ time ./inseq 1000000 > file

real    0m0.143s
user    0m0.131s
sys     0m0.011s
```

#### Carpetsmoker

```
$ cat Carpet.sh

#!/bin/bash

seq 1 $1 | while read i; do
    echo $i
done
```

.

```
$ time ./Carpet.sh 1000000 > file

 real    0m12.223s
 user    0m9.753s
 sys     0m2.140s
```

#### Hari Shankar

```
$ cat Hari.sh

#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<$1;++i))
do
  echo "$i $((RANDOM%$2))"
done
```

.

```
$ time ./Hari.sh 1000000 > file
real    0m9.729s
user    0m8.084s
sys     0m1.064s
```

As you can see from the results, my way is *slightly* faster by about 60-70*.

### Edit

Because python is great

```
$ cat Py.sh

#!/usr/bin/python

for x in xrange(1, 1000000):
print (x)
```

'

```
$ time ./Py.sh >file

real    0m0.543s
user    0m0.499s
sys     0m0.016s
```

4* slower than c++ so if the file was going to take an hour to make it would take 4 with these two lines.

#### EDIT 2

Decided to try Python and c++ on the 1000000000 line file

For a none CPU-intensive task this seems to be using a lottt of cpu

```
PID USER  %CPU   TIME+  COMMAND
56056 me  96     2:51.43 Py.sh
```

Results for Python

```
real    9m37.133s
user    8m53.550s
sys     0m8.348s
```

Results for c++

```
 real    3m9.047s
 user    2m53.400s
 sys     0m2.842s
```

Comment: @Carpetsmoker yeah probably. Can probably do it quite quickly in bash as well if you store it in an array and echo the whole thing every n numbers, instead of echoing every number.I don't understand your comment `this is not CPU-intensive` when clearly the other answers are ?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker You've lost me. Why is that relevant ? I don't know what point you are trying to make ? Also g++ is available by default on most *nixs whereas python is not.

Comment: It is relevant since an equivalent Python script is exactly 2 easy lines, and not 24 not-so-easy lines; it runs almost as fast because the C++ code isn't CPU intensive (so, little performance benefit); You can do the same with Ruby, Perl, etc. Many systems come without a C++ compiler installed, I would expect there are far more systems with Python installed.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Write an answer in python then ? I still don't understand the problem ?

Comment: There is no problem. It's just a comment that there is little performance benefit to C++ vs. other programming languages, for the benefit of future readers.